# Split records in a column separated by delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've an issue that I need help with.  I have a column with a set of string that is separated by "." (Example below) I've the query to split it by using substring and charindex the issue is the second delimiter is not always the same length so when I case it it's not splitting correctly.

```
Column A
100.11111.12.16
101.36333
101.REMOTE.01
200.ACTIVE
```

I need the above data to be split into 3 columns.

```
Column A           Column B      Column C     Column D
100.11111.12.16    100           11111          12.16
101.36333          101           36333  
101.REMOTE.01      101           REMOTE          01
200.ACTIVE         200           ACTIVE
```

As you can see the second delimiter doesn't really fall in the same position always.  The first is always after 3 so I can split it, but its the second one that I'm having issues splitting because I can't locate the exact location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this solution must to know about [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) function. Links to SUBSTRING, NULLIF, CHARINDEX functions was given earlier by respected @Pரதீப். The LEN function speaks for itself.

```
SELECT a [Column A],
  SUBSTRING(a, 1, ISNULL(p1 - 1, LEN(a))) [Column B],
  SUBSTRING(a, p1 + 1, ISNULL(p2, LEN(a) + 1) - p1 - 1) [Column C],
  SUBSTRING(a, p2 + 1, LEN(a) - p2) [Column D]
FROM(VALUES('100.11111.12.16'),
           ('101.36333'),
           ('101.REMOTE.01'),
           ('200.ACTIVE'),
           ('42170')) a(a)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', a), 0))) b(p1)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', a, p1 + 1), 0))) c(p2)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', a, p2 + 1), 0))) d(p3);
```

Check it on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/TOKRH13046).

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using string functions

```
SELECT [Column A] = t.string, 
       [Column B] = LEFT(t.string, Charindex('.', t.string) - 1), 
       [Column C] = Reverse(Parsename(Reverse(cs.string), 1)), 
       [Column D] = Stuff(cs.string, 1, NULLIF(fpos, 0), '') 
FROM   Yourtable t 
       CROSS apply(VALUES (Substring(string, Charindex('.', string) + 1, Len(string))))cs(string) 
       CROSS apply(VALUES (Charindex('.', cs.string))) p (fpos)
```

- **[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/KETQ90963)**

MSDN links :

- [Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql)
- [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql)
- [Charindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql)
- [Stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql)
- [Reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql)
- [Parsename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql)
- [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Another option using a little XML in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Column A] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('100.11111.12.16')
,('101.36333')
,('101.REMOTE.01')
,('200.ACTIVE')

Select A.* 
      ,[Column B] = B.Pos1
      ,[Column C] = B.Pos2
      ,[Column D] = substring(concat('.'+B.Pos3,'.'+B.Pos4),2,50)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(A.[Column A],'.','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as X
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum occurrences of dots is 3 then parsename can do all the job :

```
select columnA,
       parsename(reverse(columnA),1) columnB,
       parsename(reverse(columnA),2) columnC,
       parsename(reverse(columnA),3) + isnull('.'+parsename(reverse(columnA),4),'')  columnD
from table
```